# Mule ESB: Questions

Tags: web-services, service, mule, mule-studio

so I have been reading Mule in Action for some time and have gained some knowledge on the features of Mule Studio. I have several questions regarding some specifications of a project(that utilizes web services) I am working on and I would be very grateful if someone could help understand how to implement them:

-Service management: I am required to investigate the possibility of having multiple versions of a same service. Meaning if an admin decided to add a different version of the same service it should be possible to alternate between the new and previous one.
-Using Mule studio the messages should be handled by priority. I think this can be done using JMS filters.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For versioning services you should try [API Manager](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/API+Manager), it is an enterprise product.

About priorities, you are right, you can use a [JMS selector in your flow](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JMS+Transport+Reference) to only consume messages of a certain priority:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="important.queue">
    <jms:selector expression="JMSPriority=9"/>
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: So it seems I was heading in the right way. One other question please, what does mule esb offer in term of security ? For example, I think in a way those filters enforce policies and thus only allow for certain message to pass through.

Comment: For filtering you can do something manual using [filters](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Filter) or leverage [Spring security manager](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager). For WS specific security look at [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SOAP+Web+Service+Security+Example). Alternatively there are other products that run o top of Mule ESB that can help you like [Anypoint Security](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Enterprise+Security) or API Manager.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Actually, I was wondering about how to link an application (in Java/JEE) with a Mule application. Meaning having an application that calls a service in mule.

Comment: You can publish a [web service using Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF) and securing the connection like I mentioned before. Consume that service from your Java/JEE application.

Comment: I understand. Are there any tutorials on how to consume a mule service from an outside application ? thx

Comment: Sure, you can use CXF that is the same tool that Mule ESB use. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html). An other alternative that I forgot to mention is, publish a REST API using [APIKit](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/APIkit) in Mule and consume it using Jersey or Apache HTTP Client.

Comment: Thank you it s really hepful ! just to make sure though: so I have created a web service and its client as well using cxf but I am wondering about how to make the consumer (client) send a request to Mule in order to consume the web service that I deployed in Mule ? (I think that s it s usually done between service consumers and apps)

Comment: Publish your web service using Mule and make your client endpoint use the one published by Mule.